# Ruby noobster does not understand arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I'm not a programmer, but I want to become one. So, I read books, I do tutorials and I ask questions. Here is the question:

I'm trying to do a Ruby quiz – the one with the Solitaire cypher (http://rubyquiz.com/quiz1.html). I wrote some code that works pretty well, except that at one point it alters the `key_deck` array which should be a reference to the end of the program. I do not know where this happens or why.

Here is my noobish code:

```
$characters = Array ('A' .. 'Z')

def encode to_encode, input_deck
    trekljdfg = input_deck
    edeck = input_deck
    work_string = ''
    to_encode.upcase.split("").each do |char|
        if $characters.include?(char)
            work_string.concat(char)
        end
    end
    work_string = work_string + ('X' * ((5 - (work_string.length % 5)) % 5))

    keystream_string = ''
    while keystream_string.length < work_string.length do # <-- generate keystream
        edeck = permutation(edeck)
        keystream_string.concat(get_letter(edeck))
    end

    encoded = combine_with_keystream(work_string, keystream_string)
    encoded = split_string_in_groups(encoded)

    return encoded
end

def decode to_decode, input_deck
    ddeck = input_deck
    to_decode = to_decode.delete(' ')
    keystream_string = ''
    while keystream_string.length < to_decode.length do # <-- generate keystream
        ddeck = permutation(ddeck)
        keystream_string.concat(get_letter(ddeck))
    end

    array_to_decode = text_to_numbers to_decode
    array_keystream_string = text_to_numbers keystream_string
    decoded = ''
    for i in 0..(array_to_decode.length-1)
        if array_to_decode[i] >= array_keystream_string[i]
            decoded.concat($characters[(array_to_decode[i] - array_keystream_string[i])-1])
        else
            decoded.concat($characters[(array_to_decode[i] + 26 - array_keystream_string[i])-1])
        end
    end

    decoded = split_string_in_groups decoded

    return decoded
end

def permutation deck_to_change
    deck = deck_to_change
    def swap array, joker
        work_array = array
        joker_position = work_array.index(joker)
        if joker_position == (work_array.length-1)
            temp_array = work_array.slice!(1..(work_array.length-2))
            work_array = work_array + temp_array
        else
            work_array[joker_position], work_array[joker_position+1] = work_array[joker_position+1], work_array[joker_position]
        end
        return work_array
    end

    deck = swap(deck, 'A') # <-- swap first joker
    2.times do # <-- swap second joker
        deck = swap(deck, 'B')
    end

    if deck.index('A') < deck.index('B') # <-- triple cut
        joker_position1 = deck.index('A')
        joker_position2 = deck.index('B') - joker_position1
    else
        joker_position1 = deck.index('B')
        joker_position2 = deck.index('A') - joker_position1
    end
    if joker_position1 == 0
        temp_array1 = []
    else
        temp_array1 = deck.slice!(0..joker_position1-1)
    end
    if joker_position2 == deck.length-1
        temp_array2 = []
    else
        temp_array2 = deck.slice!(joker_position2+1..deck.length-1)
    end
    deck = temp_array2 + deck + temp_array1

    if (deck.last != 'A') | (deck.last != 'B') # <-- count cut
        temp_array1 = deck.slice!(0..deck.last.to_i-1)
        temp_array2 = deck.pop(1)
        deck = deck + temp_array1 + temp_array2
    end
    return deck
end

def get_letter deck
    first = deck.first
    case first
    when 'A'
        first = '53'
    when 'B'
        first = '53'
    end
    if (deck[first.to_i] == 'A') | (deck[first.to_i] == 'B')
        return ''
    else
        return $characters[((deck[first.to_i]).to_i-1) % 26]
    end
end

def text_to_numbers text
    array = []
    text.upcase.split("").each do |char|
        array.push($characters.index(char)+1)
    end
    return array
end

def combine_with_keystream string1, string2
    temp_array1 = text_to_numbers string1
    temp_array2 = text_to_numbers string2

    string = ''
    for i in 0..(temp_array1.length-1)
        tmp =  temp_array1[i] + temp_array2[i]
        if tmp > 26
            tmp = tmp - 26
        end
        string.concat($characters[tmp-1])
    end
    return string
end

def split_string_in_groups string
    return string.scan(/.{1,5}/).join(" ")
end

#-begin-------------------------

key_deck = ('1' .. '52').to_a + ['A', 'B'] # <-- this is the key deck ^^
string_to_encode = 'Code in Ruby live longer!' # <-- this is the string to be encoded
string_to_decode = 'GLNCQ MJAFF FVOMB JIYCB' # <-- this is the string to be decoded
puts "Your encoded text is: #{encode(string_to_encode, key_deck)}"
puts "Your decoded text is: #{decode(string_to_decode, key_deck)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `permutation` function alters the deck. You pass it a reference to the original deck, so any changes you do on the reference will actually change the original. Try something like this instead:

```
key_deck = [....]
...
puts "#{encode(string_to_encode, key_dec.clone}"
```

The `clone` method will make a new copy of the array for you so all changes will only apply to the copy.

Or you can just avoit the entire problem by using the `Array#shuffle` method:

```
puts "#{encode(string_to_encode, key_dec.shuffle}"
```

That will give an already shuffled deck to the `encode` function.

Comment: Thank you, it helps. About the second suggestion: I need the deck to be used in the original configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `slice!` to find your deck's permutations, which changes the input array.

The easiest solution is to `dup` the array before working on it:

```
def encode to_encode, input_deck
    trekljdfg = input_deck.dup
    edeck = input_deck.dup
    # ..
end

def decode to_decode, input_deck
    ddeck = input_deck.dup
    # ..
end
```

[`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-dup) creates a copy of the array, which you can safely mutilate.

Comment: I see. It help, thank you. That was may guess, but why that not happens with this wariable too:
`code`
def change_text text1
 text1 = 'changed text'
 return text1
end
text = 'original text'
change_text text
puts text
`code`

Comment: In this code you changed the value of the _reference_ (`text1 = ...`). When you use APIs like `slice!`(http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) you change the _object itself_ rather than the reference to it, which can be seen by anyone holding the reference. Try `text1.gsub!('i', 'I')` and see what happens.